# Episerver customize forms

Tags: episerver, episerver-forms

I installed package "EPiServer.Forms.4.5.1" from nuget. And when i creating a new form, there is no preview available. modules/_protected/EpiServer.Forms have no default view for form, but have views for form controls. 
I also want to create different forms. Is there a way to create and use two different display templates for form at the same time? And how?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple views and render forms differently depending on context. I would recommend starting with the developer guide for Forms: https://world.episerver.com/documentation/developer-guides/forms/

Comment: If only i can find the information i need. Could you provide a direct link to article about creating multiple form views?